# How to add a node at second position to the root node with xslt

Tags: xslt

I have an xml tree with a dynamic root element (not a static name) and some children under that root element. Now I want to add to the children an element at the second position with a xslt script. How can I do it?

Example:
xml:

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <element1a>
      ..
    </element1a>
  </element1>
  <element2 name="exampleName">This is text.</element2>
</root>
```

should be converted to

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <element1a>
      ..
    </element1a>
  </element1>
  <someNewElement>1234</someNewElement>
  <element2 name="exampleName">This is text.</element2>
</root>
```

What I got so far is the following. But with that solution the node is only added at the first position. I need it at the second position.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="newElement">4711</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]">
    <xsl:next-match />
    <xsl:element name="newElement">4711</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This defines a template that matches the first element child of the document element, does the normal identity template processing (using `next-match`) and then inserts your new element following it.  You could alternatively do

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*[2]">
  <xsl:element name="newElement">4711</xsl:element>
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>
```

to match the second child and insert the element before it.  The difference between the two is apparent if `<root>` has only one child element, in which case the `/*/*[1]` version would insert the `newElement` but the `/*/*[2]` would not.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]">
    <xsl:call-template name="copy" />
    <newElement>4711</newElement>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <element1a>
      ..
    </element1a>
  </element1>
  <newElement>4711</newElement>
  <element2 name="exampleName">This is text.</element2>
</root>
```

And if you actually are using XSLT 2.0, you should be able to use `<xsl:next-match />` instead of `<xsl:call-template name="copy" />`, and remove the `name` attribute from the other template.